# How to bind image to the div tag multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind my image to the div tag.it bind only to the first object and not 
all.
I stored images in azure blob storage.

```
type: "Get",
        url: "/contollerName/methodname",
        success: function (result) {
            data = JSON.parse(result);
            alert("Pic " + data.ContentType +" "+data.Content);


            $('#MyProfile').attr('src', "data:" + data.ContentType + ";base64," + data.Content);
```

this methods gives me image.and the same id i.e MyProfile I am using for div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the divs by ID. In valid HTML you must only use a ID once per page. Change it to class and reference it in jquery. Although a div has no src attribute, but you want to reference an image:

```
<div class="profilePic"><img src="value.png"/></div>
```

The jquery part:

```
  $('.profilePic img').attr('src', "data:" + data.ContentType + ";base64," + data.Content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use ID selector for multiple element!

```
var $profiles = $('.MyProfile');
$profile.forEach(element, index) {
    element.attr('src', "data:" + data.ContentType + ";base64," + data.Content);
}
```

Comment: and the element only contains last image as attribute right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a class instead of ID like $('.bindImage').attr(...).

Second one, you get multiple elements back, so you need to go through them:

```
var elements = $('.bindImage');

elements.forEach(element, index) {
    element.attr('src', "data:" + data.ContentType + ";base64," + data.Content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css id selector (`#MyProfile`) only returns the *first* element it finds on the page since ID selector should be unique on the page. It seems like you actually want to use class selector (`.cssClassHere`)